# Force g++ to indicate when library is not included

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm a computer science student taking a C++ class right now.

I'm developing on Ubuntu with VSCode and g++ as my compiler.

I had points deducted from my last assignment because I forgot to include the string library, so the grader had a compile error.

However, on my machine, although the string library isn't included, it still compiles and runs without issue or warning.

It seems like g++ catches this mistake and includes it without telling me? Is there a way I can force g++ to indicate that I forgot the string library?

This is the code that I have experienced this issue with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string output = "";
    char inputChar;

    // ask for input while the inputChar is not '0'
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a character: ";
        cin.get(inputChar);              // get input char from user
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');           // ignore the newline character
        switch( tolower(inputChar) )     // inputChar lowercase for simplified switch statement
        {
            // if inputChar is a vowel, capitalize and append to output string
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                output += toupper(inputChar);
                break;
            // if char is 0, exit switch without doing anything
            case '0':
                break;
            // all other characters are appended to string in lowercase
            default:
                output += tolower(inputChar);
                break;
        }
    } while (inputChar != '0');

    // print full output string and exit
    cout << "Your string: " << output << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just include any (standard) headers when ever you use them. These might be or not included with other standard headers, but you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

An #include is barely more than a literal cut-and-paste of the contents of the file being included (with macros expanded, and file/line markers inserted so the source can be traced.)

When you include *iostream*, if it internally includes *string*, then you've included string transitively.  This is considered a bad because there's no guarantee that standard library headers will include other headers, so your code isn't portable and has a small dependency on the version of the standard library you're using.

If you add an include for *string* into your code, due to preprocessor protections against duplicate header inclusions, it will be so thoroughly suppressed that no evidence that the include even existed will be present in its output.  The compiler has nothing to work with, and cannot reliably supply the warning you would like without false positives.

For example:  Let's say we have a .cpp file with a main, and a header called a.hpp:

Header "a.hpp":

```
#pragma once

namespace A {
    void a_function() { }
}
```

Header "b.hpp"

```
#pragma once
#include "a.hpp"

namespace B {
  void b_function() { }
}
```

and main.cpp now looks like this:

```
#include "b.hpp" // only include b...

int main() { A::a_function(); } // ... but use something in a.hpp
```

This compiles but has no warnings.  The preprocessed output looks like this:

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "b.hpp" 1     
# 1 "a.hpp" 1
namespace A {
  void a_function() { }
}
# 3 "b.hpp" 2

namespace B {
    void b_function() { }
}
# 2 "main.cpp" 2

int main() { }
```

Seems reasonable, and we can see that a was included by B, and should issue an error, right?

Let's fix it and try again:

```
#include "b.hpp"
#include "a.hpp"

int main() { }
```

Preprocessing once more:

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "b.hpp" 1     
# 1 "a.hpp" 1
namespace A {
  void a_function() { }
}
# 3 "b.hpp" 2

namespace B {
    void b_function() { }
}
# 2 "main.cpp" 2

int main() { }
```

100% identical to before.  **We fixed the problem but there is no indication in the preprocessed output.**

Unless the preprocessor gave more information, no change in the compiler could address your request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your grader has a custom include directory and is using the `-nostdinc` and `-nostdinc++` options on g++, or they're compiling the code on a different OS or with a different compiler.

At first, I thought this was a lack of the -Wall option, but it seems the warning class that actually flags missing includes only works for C or Objective-C, not C++. Your code compiles on my system without error for both g++ and clang++. That doesn't mean my thought before about trying another compiler was wrong, just useless for this issue.

Simulating an environment like the grader is using would be quite a bit of work. But as I spent some time trying to do that just to sanity check my last answer, I had a realization: if you run your code through `g++ -E`, it will tell you all of the effective code that will be compiled, including where every single line involved comes from. You can use this to see all of the header files included in your code so you can include them all.

On the one hand, this exercise is rather annoying. On the other hand, it's not nearly as annoying as trying to port some code from a platform you have no reference of, and the author made no effort to make sure all the libraries were spelled out. On the gripping hand, when trying to port some code from a very different source system, the libraries aren't all named exactly the same way, and so the programmer going through this wouldn't necessarily help - especially since compilers are pretty good about complaining about missing header files that matter, and you can fairly quickly look up the names of the routines or types that are at issue to find out what to do about that on your system. I think in the end I'm inclined to assume that your grader was probably working under instruction from an academic who thinks they're helping to mold students to be able to handle unknowns they will encounter, without having much of an idea of what unknowns you will be likely to encounter. That's frustrating and sad, but so is life sometimes. We do what we can do, we don't do what we can't do, but we may not know what we can't do until we try.